# lotus notes agent 'after new mail has arrived' not running

Tags: lotus-notes

We're on Domino 901FP4.  We have an attachment extraction agent that gets emails and extracts the attachments to a directory on the server.  I created it 5 years ago and has been working fine.  But about 10 days ago, it just stopped working.  No errors are generated.  The emails remain unread (since the agent isn't firing).  The 'disable background agents' is not checked.

Interestingly, in order to test this agent initially, I wrote a triggering agent.  It does a 'run on server' on the extraction agent.  If I run this triggering agent, the extraction agent runs and pulls out the attachments out as it should.  But it isn't able to do it on its own when a new email comes in.

I did upgrade the mail db using the 901 mail template.  That did not help.

Any ideas what might be going on with this?
thanks
clem

Comment: Have you restarted the router?

Comment: Hey Rich     I hadn't but did not and no change -- the agent is just sitting there.

Comment: Hey Clem! Hmmm... How about re-signing it?  Oh, and have you seen this http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21099178 and have you by any chance moved the signer's mail file recently?

Comment: I did see this ibm info document and the agent is on the same server as my email db -- I signed it.  Still nothing.  Very odd.  I upgraded the server with a fix pack but recall if that was around that time.  I'll have to check the logs.

Answer (score 0):

It fixed itself magically after a rebooted Windows.  :-\